# Change child control data-source according to Pivot selected index change

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I am trying to change the data source of a child element (in this case a custom user control) of Pivot, when a selected index change occurs.
My Pivot XAML looks like this

```
            <Pivot x:Name="PivotItemsContainer" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.headerElement, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" >
            <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:HeaderUIModel">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local1:AddressInfoControl></local1:AddressInfoControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </Pivot>
```

And on selected index change

```
        private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddressInfoControl aic = new AddressInfoControl();
        switch (PivotItemsContainer.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                aic.Numbers = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                aic.Numbers = 1;
                break;
            default:
                // code block
                break;
        }
    }
```

My usercontrol code

```
 AddressInfoMock aim = new AddressInfoMock();
    private int _numbers;
    public int Numbers
    {
        set
        {
            _numbers = value;

            //when the numbers be changed
            if (Numbers == 0)
            {
                AddressContainer.DataContext = aim.GetRightBoxDetails();
            }
            else
            {
                AddressContainer.DataContext = aim.GetLeftBoxDetails();

            }

        }
        get
        {
            return _numbers;
        }
    }

    public AddressInfoControl()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        if (Numbers == 0)
        {
            AddressContainer.DataContext = aim.GetRightBoxDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            AddressContainer.DataContext = aim.GetLeftBoxDetails();
        }

    }

}
```

This code always takes Numbers as `0` on selected index change. I believe this is happening because of  `InitializeComponent();`. How can i make this work.  So that when selected index is 0 I get rightbox data and when it is 1 I get leftbox data?

Comment: About "This code always takes Numbers as 0 on selected index change", do you mean the Number of AddressInfoControl in xaml is still 0? From your code, when the SelectionChanged event is triggered, you create a new AddressInfoControl, then change its Numder based on the SelectedIndex. But didn't change the Number of AddressInfoControl which is in xaml. Why do you create a new AddressInfoControl instance in SelectionChanged event? Do you actually want to get the AddressInfoControl in PivotItem from xaml?

Comment: I just want my user control to know that which pivot item is presently active and bind data accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change Numbers property based on the selectedIndex of pivotItem, you can declare a Numbers [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties) and then use ElementName to bind with the SelectedIndex of Pivot. In that case, you don't need to subscribe the SelectionChanged event.

.xaml:

```
<Pivot x:Name="PivotItemsContainer" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.headerElement, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:UIModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:AddressInfoControl Numbers="{Binding ElementName=PivotItemsContainer,Path=SelectedIndex}"></local:AddressInfoControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

UserControl.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumbersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Numbers",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(AddressInfoControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLabelChanged))
);

private static void OnLabelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int s = (int)e.NewValue; //the newValue of Numbers
    if (s == 0)
    {
        //rightbox 
    }
    else if(s == 1)
    {
        //leftbox

    }
}

public int Numbers
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(NumbersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NumbersProperty, value); }
}

public AddressInfoControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```